# kibana 6.x Configure Kibana to encrypt communications between the browser and the Kibana server?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5

what are the steps required to configure https in browser and kibanna server. i downloaded some certification from internet and it is saying not a secure one. it is for our production environment. my company may provide valid ssl certificate. in that case what are the things required?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/configuring-tls.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/configuring-tls.html), you have to modify your `kibana.yml` such as:

```
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key
server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
```